# SimpleTest, setting $_SESSION variables

Tags: php, simpletest

I am doing a POST request to this webservice

```
<?
    session_start();
    $request = array();
    $request = $_POST;
    echo $_SESSION['USER'];
    echo $_SESSION['ORG'];
?>
```

using simpletest API,

```
class GetTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * Unit Test function checking POST requests
     * 
     * @return NULL
     */
    function testPostRequest()
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['ORG'] = 'someorg';
        $_SESSION['USER'] = 'someuser';
        $value = array("postdata"=>"somepost")
        $temp = $this->post("127.0.0.1/create.php",$value);
        print $temp;
    }
}
```

When i execute the unittest script it is not printing anything, that means session variables are not getting set. Is there some other way to make it work? Both these scripts are on same server.

Comment: line 2 of your first script is useless

Comment: `$_SESSION` variables are global (**super**-global), and cannot be normally tested. Also, I don't see you use any of the session variables in your test.

Comment: `session_start()` executes in the context of the unit test snippet, with a local http client. The `session_start()` in your webservice example executes in another context. Thus two distinct sessions. Which is why no output occurs.

Comment: @mario: Thanks, even if these two scripts are on same webserver wont it work?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: actually, these session variables are set by another webservice (like user login), and I only have to test this script, not the login script, so in unittest script I am trying to do the same that loginscript do ie. authenticate user and set these variables. It should be okay, right?

Comment: Of course you can make it work. Pass on the test scripts local session_id as cookie `PHPSESSID` per curl or whatever the `->post` method uses.

Comment: @mario: Thanks again, I found one more way to do it (although your sounds better), i passed the ORG and USER variables along with post data (just for unittest purpose) and added session variable from there in the webservice. Although I have to add few more lines to the webservice to make it work.